# Difference between the source MAC address in an ARP message packet and the source MAC address specified while encapsulating it?

Tags: networking, wireshark, tcp, arp

I am trying to understand how ARP works and the format of an ARP packet. Look at the circled fields in the figure below:

[image]

In this example they have given different MAC addresses in both the fields. I cannot see how that is possible? Under what scenario will these two be different?

And if not why are we adding redundant information while encapsulating it?

Though I do think since they have different lengths (*one is fixed 6 bytes while the other is variable ..why??*) they must be for different addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may be a legitimate typo. The address length in the ARP packets is variable because different layer-2 protocols have different address lengths. Don't make the mistake of thinking only about ethernet.

You should study [RFC 826](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc826) in order to understand ARP:

> This protocol was originally designed for the DEC/Intel/Xerox 10Mbit
> Ethernet.  It has been generalized to allow it to be used for other
> types of networks.  Much of the discussion will be directed toward the
> 10Mbit Ethernet.  Generalizations, where applicable, will follow the
> Ethernet-specific discussion.

See the emphasized text:

> Why is it done this way??
>
> Periodic broadcasting is definitely not desired.  Imagine 100
> workstations on a single Ethernet, each broadcasting address
> resolution information once per 10 minutes (as one possible set of
> parameters).  This is one packet every 6 seconds.  This is almost
> reasonable, but what use is it?  The workstations aren't generally
> going to be talking to each other (and therefore have 100 useless
> entries in a table); they will be mainly talking to a mainframe, file
> server or bridge, but only to a small number of other workstations
> (for interactive conversations, for example). The protocol described
> in this paper distributes information as it is needed, and only once
> (probably) per boot of a machine.
>
> This format does not allow for more than one resolution to be done in
> the same packet.  This is for simplicity.  If things were multiplexed
> the packet format would be considerably harder to digest, and much of
> the information could be gratuitous.  Think of a bridge that talks
> four protocols telling a workstation all four protocol addresses,
> three of which the workstation will probably never use.
>
> This format allows the packet buffer to be reused if a reply is
> generated; a reply has the same length as a request, and several of
> the fields are the same.
>
> The value of the hardware field (ar$hrd) is taken from a list for this
> purpose.  Currently the only defined value is for the 10Mbit Ethernet
> (ares_hrd$Ethernet = 1).  There has been talk of using this protocol
> for Packet Radio Networks as well, and this will require another value
> as will other future hardware mediums that wish to use this protocol.
>
> For the 10Mbit Ethernet, the value in the protocol field (ar$pro) is
> taken from the set ether_type$.  This is a natural reuse of the
> assigned protocol types.  Combining this with the opcode (ar$op) would
> effectively halve the number of protocols that can be resolved under
> this protocol and would make a monitor/debugger more complex (see
> Network Monitoring and Debugging below).  It is hoped that we will
> never see 32768 protocols, but Murphy made some laws which don't allow
> us to make this assumption.
>
> In theory, the length fields (ar$hln and ar$pln) are redundant, since
> the length of a protocol address should be determined by the hardware
> type (found in ar$hrd) and the protocol type (found in ar$pro).  It is
> included for optional consistency checking, and for network monitoring
> and debugging (see below).
>
> The opcode is to determine if this is a request (which may cause a
> reply) or a reply to a previous request.  16 bits for this is
> overkill, but a flag (field) is needed.
>
> ***The sender hardware address and sender protocol address are absolutely necessary.  It is these fields that get put in a
> translation table.***
>
> The target protocol address is necessary in the request form of the
> packet so that a machine can determine whether or not to enter the
> sender information in a table or to send a reply.  It is not
> necessarily needed in the reply form if one assumes a reply is only
> provoked by a request.  It is included for completeness, network
> monitoring, and to simplify the suggested processing algorithm
> described above (which does not look at the opcode until AFTER putting
> the sender information in a table).
>
> The target hardware address is included for completeness and network
> monitoring.  It has no meaning in the request form, since it is this
> number that the machine is requesting.  Its meaning in the reply form
> is the address of the machine making the request. In some
> implementations (which do not get to look at the 14.byte ethernet
> header, for example) this may save some register shuffling or stack
> space by sending this field to the hardware driver as the hardware
> destination address of the packet.
>
> There are no padding bytes between addresses.  The packet data should
> be viewed as a byte stream in which only 3 byte pairs are defined to
> be words (ar$hrd, ar$pro and ar$op) which are sent most significant
> byte first (Ethernet/PDP-10 byte style).

[RFC 826](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc826) has been updated by [RFC 5227](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5227) and [RFC 5494](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5494).